# How to fetch data from push notification when app is turned off?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to fetch data from push notification when app is turned off. I am using the following code given below:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler 
{
    NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@”aps”];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive){
    // user tapped notification
         NSLog(@"results%@",aps);
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    } else {
    // app is active             
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
}
```

In above code NSLog(@"results%@",aps); doesn't get print the values when app is in background. Please Help me out

Comment: Explore PushKit it might help...

Comment: Is your problem resolved? then close this question.

Answer (score 3):

didReceiveRemoteNotification works only when you tap on notification. so it will provide you data only when you tap on notification and your app will get open.

If you want to get NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@”aps”]; when your app is in kill state, then you have to implement pushkit framework.

You can download sample code from 1 my answer

[Can someone share a sample code of iOS Xamarin PushKit in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235676/can-someone-share-a-sample-code-of-ios-xamarin-pushkit-in-c/38303750#38303750)

[Register for voip notifications outside of app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868158/register-for-voip-notifications-outside-of-app-delegate/38147175#38147175)

**Source** https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

When is app is turned off or terminated to be precise , `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called for obvious reasons
Appdelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` launchOptions provides a solution for this.
The Launchoptions is basically a dictionary to tell the app in which way it was launched.For your implementation you need to check if launchOptions has any value in the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`, like so ()

`let userInfo = launchOptionForApp[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary`

your userInfo dictionary has the json you will need to parse and implement your further logic

Answer (score 0):

Sample change from server end that done the trick for me.

```
{
    aps = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        sound : ""
    };
}
```

Comment: Making "content-available" : 1 will not help you, if you have push kit frame work then only it will work. with simple apple push notification you would not be able to get data when app is turned off.

Comment: So what should i have to do?

Comment: Check my answer. to get push notification data when your app is in terminated state, you have to apply push kit, it will invoke your app for 30 seconds in background and you would be able to get data from push kit payload even when your app is in terminated state. didReceiveRemoteNotification provides you data only when you tap on push notification which is visible in notification tray.

Comment: Please send me the link of answer

Comment: It is here only. check my below answer.

Comment: But this code is in Xamrin i think. I need code in objective c

Comment: No, its swift code, just understand that delegate methods and implement in objective c. Got it.